# How can I send button value from ejs to server in for loop with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I have some dataset includes crypto coin names, symbols etc.
When I clicked the button, I expect to see coin symbol in console. First one is okey but others did not work. I see empty. I want to see all matching datas with name or symbol when clicked the details. Where is my mistake ?

My ejs

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:850px; margin:15px; text-align: center;">
    <caption>
      <h1>Coins</h1>
    </caption>
    <thead style="font-size: 20px;">
      <tr style="border:2px solid">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Slug</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% for (i=0; i<100; i++){ %>
      <tr>     
            <td> <%= cName[i] %> </td>
            <td> <%= symbol[i] %> </td>
            <td>
              <form method="post" id="form" action="/">
              <input id="hiddeninput" name="hiddeninput" type="hidden" />
              <button id="coinName" value="<%= symbol[i] %>" name="buttonname">Detail</button> </td> //Here comes from Mongo like BTC,ETH..
            </form>

            //and some td's

      </tr>
      <% } %>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <script>
      $('#coinName').on('click', function(){
        $('#hiddeninput').val($(this).val());
      });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ejs looks like

| Name | Slug | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bitcoin | BTC | DetailButton |
| Ethereum | ETH | DetailButton |

Server.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const name = [];
const symbol = [];
const price = [];
const date = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("cryptoDb");
        dbo.collection("coinTable").find({}).toArray(function (err, finds) {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (i = 0; i < finds[0].result.length; i++) {
                name.push(finds[0].result[i].name);
                symbol.push(finds[0].result[i].symbol);
                price.push(finds[0].result[i].price);
                date.push(finds[0].result[i].date);
            }

            res.render('index', {
                cName: name,
                symbol: symbol,
                len: finds[0].result.length,
                cPrice:price,
                cDate:date
            });
            db.close();
        });
    });
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.hiddeninput);
    //Here is my function, fetch all datas from Mongo where matches hiddeninput

  
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`port: ${server.address().port}`);
}
)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: IDs must be unique. Just have one form. The submit button name and value will submit the button that is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Just have one form. The submit button name and value will submit the button that is clicked

No need for script

```html
<form method="post" id="form" action="/">
  <table style="width:850px; margin:15px; text-align: center;">
    <caption>
      <h1>Coins</h1>
    </caption>
    <thead style="font-size: 20px;">
      <tr style="border:2px solid">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Slug</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% for (i=0; i<100; i++){ %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= cName[i] %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= symbol[i] %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button name="coinName" value="<%= symbol[i] %>">Detail</button> </td> //Here comes from Mongo like BTC,ETH..
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```